# How to load custom keyboard in a specific app on button press?

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

This is my very first post here. So please ignore all my mistake. I have developed an android app. I needed a custom keyboard so that I can use local language. So I've created a custom keyboard after searching on internet. Now I want to load the keyboard when a specific button clicked from the app and also dismiss and set android's default keyboard when same button clicked again. Please can anyone help me!

## 1.This is say write.class from where I want to load the custom keyboard.

```
btnKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    //                want to load the keyboard here!
    }
});
```

## 2.This is from the Keyboard.class.

```
public class keyboardPE extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{
    private KeyboardView keyboardView;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    Boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch(primaryCode){
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                caps = !caps;
                if(caps){
                    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty_extra);
                    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
                    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
                }
                else {
                    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
                    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
                    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
                }
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;
            default:
                char code = (char)primaryCode;
//                if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
//                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
//                }
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        keyboardView = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return keyboardView;
    }

    private void playClick(int keyCode){
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch(keyCode){
            case 32:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            case 10:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

}
```

## 3. The AndroidManifest file.

```
    <activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
        <service android:name=".keyboard.keyboardPE" android:label="@string/simple_ime"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method"/>
            <inte`enter code here`nt-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    
        <activity
            android:name=".Write"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```